# Node only partially rendered near edge of plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a relatively simple chart of a number line, and when one of the nodes is too close to the edge of the plot, it gets cut off.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\columnwidth,
  axis y line=none,
  axis lines=left,
  axis line style={-},
  xmin=0,
  xmax=1,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  xlabel=$\mu$,
  scatter/classes={o={mark=*}},
  restrict y to domain=0:1,
  xtick={0,1}
]
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:0, 0) -- (axis cs:0,.05);
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:.4, 0) -- (axis cs:.4,.05);
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$B$}] at (axis cs:0.0,0.05) {};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$A$}] at (axis cs:0.4,0.05) {};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$b$}] at (axis cs:0.2,0.02) {};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$a$}] at (axis cs:0.7,0.02) {};
\end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The Result:

[image: Partially rendered node label]

How do I get the B to fully render?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default any paths inside the `axis` bounding box is clipped, this is what cuts the B. To turn off clipping, add `clip=false` to the axis options.

Clipping is discussed in section **4.19.2 Clipping** of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) (for version 1.8 of `pgfplots`, dated 2013-03-07).

As mentioned by Jake in a comment: In version 1.8 of `pgfplots` the key `clip mode=individual` was introduced, which will clip plot lines, but not normal nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\columnwidth,
  axis y line=none,
  axis lines=left,
  axis line style={-},
  xmin=0,
  xmax=1,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  xlabel=$\mu$,
  scatter/classes={o={mark=*}},
  restrict y to domain=0:1,
  xtick={0,1},
  clip=false    % <-- new addition
  % clip mode=individual  % alternative
]
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:0, 0) -- (axis cs:0,.05);
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:.4, 0) -- (axis cs:.4,.05);
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$B$}] at (axis cs:0.0,0.05) {};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$A$}] at (axis cs:0.4,0.05) {};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$b$}] at (axis cs:0.2,0.02) {};
\node[coordinate,label=above:{$a$}] at (axis cs:0.7,0.02) {};
\end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I avoid clipping a node added to addplot but the plot line should be clipped?

Comment: @Hotschke Did you try what is mentioned in the last paragraph before the code block?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this.

Comment: I mean something like this: `\addplot gnuplot{cos(x)} node[pos=0, pin={90:peak}]{};`

Comment: @Hotschke IIUC, that's a bit different, I would guess the `pin` is part of the same path as the plot, which would make it a bit harder I think. Why not add a `coordinate` and `pos=0`, and add the node afterwards? I.e. `\addplot ... coordinate[pos=0] (a);` and then `\node [pin...] at (a) {};`

Comment: There is a diffference w.r.t pins between adding directly a node to addplot or adding a coordinate and referencing it by a new separate node. A pin edge of pgfplots has no `sep` to the data line/markers, but a tikz node has. This can be compensated by ` \node[pin={[pin edge={-, shorten <=-3pt }] at (a) {text}`.