# pgfplots: the margins "eat" some parts of my graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

### Question

I use `pgfplots` with the `ultra thick` option ans without explicitly giving the domain for the y-axis.

It seems that in this case, some part of my graph is "eaten" by the margin: see the picture below to understand what I mean.

Is there a way to avoid this?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={->},  % arrows on the axis
                    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
                    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
                    grid = major
                    }}

\begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=5]
\addplot[orange,smooth, ultra thick] {sin(deg(x))} ;                 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that everything outside the `axis` is clipped, and with thick lines at the edge of the edge, part of them is chopped off (similar to [Node only partially rendered near edge of plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107812/node-only-partially-rendered-near-edge-of-plot/127904#127904)). You could add `clip=false` to turn off clipping, or extend the `y` axis a little bit, e.g. with `enlarge y limits={rel=0.01}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={->},  % arrows on the axis
                    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
                    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
                    grid = major,
                    enlarge y limits={rel=0.01}
                    %clip=false
                    }}

\begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=5]
\addplot[orange,smooth, ultra thick] {sin(deg(x))} ;                 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```