# How to increase the canvas of a tikzpicture without scaling plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, tikz-node

This is my first post, sorry for any mistake :D.

I have this code using TeXnicCenter program, and LaTeX-> PS-> PDF mode:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.489,ymin=-1,ymax=2]
            \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
            \addplot [domain=0:3.989,fill=gray!60] (\x,{1})\closedcycle;
            \addplot [domain=0:3.989,samples=100] {cos((5*x+1) r)+0.5};
            \draw[<->] (axis cs:0,-0.1) -- (axis cs:1.266,-0.1) node[below] {\footnotesize $T$};
            \draw (axis cs:1.266,1) -- (axis cs:1.266,-0.1);
            \draw[<-] (axis cs:0.05,1.05) -- (axis cs:0.4,1.5) node[above] {\footnotesize $A\, v(p)$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

which the "canvas" of the tikzpicture is, I think:

[image: Canvas of the tikzpicture]

Now if I want to put some text, like

> Potencia almacenada en, por ejemplo, el bobinado de un motor, que se
>   devuelve a la compañía eléctrica

with `\footnotesize` size. With this, the canvas maintains the size, so the text does not shown. For example, I add this text in the next code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.489,ymin=-1,ymax=2]
            \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
            \addplot [domain=0:3.989,fill=gray!60] (\x,{1})\closedcycle;
            \addplot [domain=0:3.989,samples=100] {cos((5*x+1) r)+0.5};
            \draw[<->] (axis cs:0,-0.1) -- (axis cs:1.266,-0.1) node[below] {\footnotesize $T$};
            \draw (axis cs:1.266,1) -- (axis cs:1.266,-0.1);
            \draw[<-] (axis cs:0.05,1.05) -- (axis cs:0.4,1.5) node[above] {\footnotesize $A\, v(p)$};
            \draw[<-] (axis cs:0.45,-0.2) -- (axis cs:0.2,-1) node[text width=4.5cm,below right] {\footnotesize Potencia almacenada en, por ejemplo, el bobinado de un motor, que se devuelve a la compañía eléctrica};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: The text is not displayed]

**I do not want this.** What's more, I must add more text, so I am in problems. If I change the `ymin` value to `ymin=-3` I can see the text, but the graphic stretches, and it looks ugly.

So the question is, **is there a way to change the size of the canvas to cover more space, without changing the size of the graphic?** I do not want to modify the scale of the graph, or anything like that. I just want something like this:

[image: How I would like it to stay]

to put text within the `axis` environment, and keeping the size of the graph.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Try by using options `enlarge x limits=false, enlarge y limits=false` inside brackets, and increase `ymin` to `-2`.

Comment: Using LaTeX->PS->PDF with TikZ is asking for trouble.  The whole point of TikZ is to use built in PDF functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and thanks for the welcome @Cragfelt ! It is the same :( :

Comment: I don't know how to put images in the answers section (I press CTRL+G but it does not work).
If I add those options in the `axis` environment and changes the `ymin` value to `-2` is the same: the graphic changes in size, looking ugly, as in the previous image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you just place the text outside the `axis`, like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[yshift=-2cm, axis lines=center, xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.489,ymin=-1,ymax=2]
            \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
            \addplot [domain=0:3.989,fill=gray!60] (\x,{1})\closedcycle;
            \addplot [domain=0:3.989,samples=100] {cos((5*x+1) r)+0.5};
            \draw[<->] (axis cs:0,-0.1) -- (axis cs:1.266,-0.1) node[below] {\footnotesize $T$};
            \draw (axis cs:1.266,1) -- (axis cs:1.266,-0.1);
            \draw[<-] (axis cs:0.05,1.05) -- (axis cs:0.4,1.5) node[above] {\footnotesize $A\, v(p)$};
            \end{axis}
    \draw[<-] (1.3,-0.4) -- (1,-2) node[text width=5.5cm, below right, font=\footnotesize] {Potencia almacenada en, por ejemplo, el bobinado de un motor, que se devuelve a la compañía eléctrica};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Some changes I made:

1. `[..., font=\footnotesize]` instead of `{\footnotesize...}`.
2. Put `text width=5.5cm` so the text does not break.
3. Put in preamble `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` so you do not get a
   warning. It is mandatory when you work with `pgfplots`. Refer to
   [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403020/125434).
4. Write `yshift=-2cm` inside axis options so the text shifts to top.

Comment: That works pretty well! I never used the sentence `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}`, here neither, but it still works. What does that sentence mean?
Also, how did you calculate the coordinates to add the node outside the `axis` scope? Trying manually? I know I could add it on the outside, but it bothered me that I had to manually calculate the exact position.
Thanks

Comment: @manooooh Thank you for accepting my answer. I have edited it to respond your concerns. (And yes, I tried it manually) `:)`

Comment: @manooooh You could add a `\coordinate` *inside* the `axis`, and then draw the line outside, using that named coordinate as the end point of the arrow. But what you're really after is to add the option `clip mode=individual` to the `axis` options, which will disable clipping of `\node`, `\draw` etc., while keeping the clipping of `\addplot`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107812/node-only-partially-rendered-near-edge-of-plot/127904#127904